# convert String date to java.util.date in java

Tags: java

how to convert string date to java.util.date in java .

`String date="12-12-2014 10:00:00"`

`Date d=2014-12-12 10:00:00;`

Need this string date in date formate

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
String test="12-12-2014 10:00:00";
Date date=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(test);
String OutputDate=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss").format(date);
System.out.println(OutputDate);
```

**Output :**

```
2014-12-12 10:00:00
```

The dig over here is to parse a string with date attributes using `SimpleDateFormat` into `java.util.Date`.

For more on `SimpleDateFormat` visit [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) link.

Comment: its giving out put as Fri Dec 12 10:00:00 IST 2014 .I need output date as 2014-12-12 10:00:00

Comment: Do you want same output format as well?

Comment: I have corrected my answer as per your required output.

Comment: I need out put as Date formate.  String OutputDate=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss").format(date); the out put is String

Comment: `Date` has predefined `toString()` so it prints as per its definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String date = "12-12-2014 10:00:00";
DateFormat inputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
DateFormat outputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
System.out.println(outputDateFormat.format(inputDateFormat.parse(date)));

Output:
2014-12-12 10:00:00
```

Basically you need to [parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) your date in the format provided and from one format (inputDateFormat) you need to convert it to the other [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29) (done by outputDateFormat).

Comment: Its working ,But the out put is string type.I need as java.util.date type

Comment: If you want date output then you could just say `Date date = inputDateFormat.parse(date);` we cant change toString() of Date (i.e. String format of Date object) unfortunately to print it as per what you need hence we used formatter and its going to return us String object.

Comment: I tried this but ist giving output as Fri Dec 12 10:00:00 IST 2014 .need as 2014-12-12 10:00:00 in date formate